# Core layer exception error my program is crashing

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My Business Layer

```
public IResult Register(UserRegisterDto userRegisterDto, string role)
        {
            try
            {
               
                ValidationTool.Validate(new RegisterDtoValidator(), userRegisterDto);

               ....
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw;
                
            }
        }
```

My ExceptionMiddleware

```
private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception e)
        {
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            string message = "Internal Server Error";
            int statusCodes = httpContext.Response.StatusCode;
            if (e.GetType() == typeof(ValidationException))
            {
                message = e.Message;
                statusCodes = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            }
            return httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorDetails
            {
                StatusCode = statusCodes,
                Message = message
            }.ToString());
        }
```

And My Api Controllers

```
 public IActionResult RegisterActor(UserRegisterDto userRegisterDto)
        {

            var result = _authService.Register(userRegisterDto, Role.default_actor.ToString());
            if (!result.Success)
            {
                return BadRequest(result.Message);
            }
            return Ok(result);            
        }
```

My Problem My program crash when I have some error from business layer. When there are some mistakes, error come to the Middleware. I want to program not crash direct come my middleware

For Example
[image]

I chance database name and program crach But I want

```
{
    "Message": "Internal Server Error",
    "StatusCode": 500
}
```

Because My Middleware running.

**I guess it's all about throwing

```
    catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
            
        }
```

Comment: check out this post: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: ClassLibrary(Business or Services), I use "try cache{ throw;}". But I dont crashing program, errors come my WebApi and then go to the CustomMiddleware. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there is a part missing. Where do you connect the `HandleExceptionAsync` task as a middleware to your project?

You probably need something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Middleware used to catch all exceptions and log them as errors and return a uniform API response for all errors.
/// </summary>
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly bool _isDevelopmentEnvrionment;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _next = next;
        _isDevelopmentEnvrionment = env.IsDevelopment();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method used to pipe any request through the error handling middleware and surrounding it with try-catch
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="httpContext">HttpContext needs to be passed</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
        }
    }

    // Your HandleExceptionAsync method here
}
```

and then connect it in your `Startup.cs` file in the `Configure` method:

```
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
```